# How to delete everything between two 2 lines (34 to 51)?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a lot of documents that i need to delete everything that are between this to lines 34 to 51

The documents dosn´t any form to use a

```
"Here is the beginning of the line 34" random text
Random text
Random text
Random text
Random text
Random text
    .
    .
    .
    .
"Here is the beginning of the line 51" more random text
```

(the code dont have textualy "line 34 or line 51")
How can this be done?

I currently try to use some regular expression to use in the notepad++ but i dont now how to indicate to go to "x" line and delete everything before the line "y"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `((?:.*?[\n]){33})((?:.*?[\n]){18})(.*)`

With checkbox "dot match EOL" checked.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gRajFb/1)

And replace with `$1$3`

Comment: I'm unable to say if there are 17 or 18 lines to remove tonight, for that I upvote your answer.

Comment: This doesn't work with Windows EOL (i.e. `\r\n)`

Comment: @Toto: It does when the checkbox "dot match EOL" is checked. The pattern is written with this option (that's why it ends with `(.*)` and it uses non-greedy quantifiers).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: You're right, but it's better to show all the flags in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
(?:.*\r?\n){33}\K(?:.*\r?\n?){17}
```

with an empty string as replacement.

34 - 1 = 33
51 - 34 = 17

with the cursor at the start of the file and apply it only once. (also uncheck *dot match EOL* checkbox)

---

if you think that putting the cursor at the start of the file is too annoying, check the *loop* checkbox and use this pattern (that tests the beginning of the file):

```
(?<![\s\S])(?:.*\r?\n){33}\K(?:.*\r?\n?){17}
```

same replacement.

Comment: I'd use `\A` instaed of `(?<![\s\S])` and `\R` instead of `\r?\n`

Comment: @Toto: Yes me too for the `\A` but I don't know why this escape sequence was refused yesterday by npp (and it works today). About `\R`, it's short and useful, but keep in mind that it's only an alias for an alternation with many branches inside an atomic group, so that is in reality more complicated than a simple `\r?\n`.